# Not working filter in CGridView (YII)

Tags: php, yii

Not working filter elements in the CGridView. Tell me how to fix this? For example, you must select a category, choose "Baby", but nothing happens.
[image]
**SiteController**

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new Page;
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Page', array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort' => array(
                'defaultOrder'=>array(
                    'created'=>"DESC"
                )),
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>30,
            ),
        ));

        // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
        // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
        $this->render('index', array('dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,'model'=>$model));
    }
```

**index.php**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'enableSorting'=>true,
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns' => array(
        'title' => array(
            'name'=>'title',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>'CHtml::link($data->title,Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/page/".$data->id)',
            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:250px;'),
        ),
        'created' => array(
            'name' => 'created',
            'value' => 'date("j.m.Y H:i", $data->created)',
            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:90px;'),
            'type'=>'raw',
        ),
        'category_id' => array(
            'name' => 'category_id',
            'value' => '$data->category->title',
            'filter' => Category::allCategory(),
            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:150px; text-align:center;'),
            'type'=>'raw',
            'sortable'=>TRUE
        ),
        'subcategory_id' => array(
            'name' => 'subcategory_id',
            'value' => '$data->subcategory->title',
            'filter' => Subcategory::allCategory(),
            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:150px; text-align: center;'),
            'type'=>'raw',
        ),
        'condition_id' => array(
            'name' => 'condition_id',
            'value'=> '$data->condition->title',
            'filter' => Condition::allAttributes(),
            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style'=>'width:90px;'),
            'type'=>'raw',
        ),
    ),
));
```

***Thanks in advance for answers and assistance.***

Comment: Request URL if I select Category::Baby is  domain.com/site/index?Page%5Btitle%5D=&Page%5Bcreated%5D=&Page%5Bcategory_id%5D=3&Page%5Bsubcategory_id%5D=&Page%5Bcondition_id%5D=&Page_page=1&ajax=yw0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not load the POST/GET data from the request, and that is why you do not get any filtered values.
There are more approaches to this, I show you a simple one i use mostly;

in your controler do this:

```
    $model = new Page;
    if(isset($_GET['Page']))
        $model->attributes =$_GET['Page'];


        $dataProvider = $model->search();
```

In you `Page` model, find the `search` function, and adapt your custom Dataprovider there (or make a copy ot the search and use it later)

That should do the job. The important part is - you have to set the attributes somewhere, from the GET request.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dataprovider that will respond to your query.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(), // <== search() function in your model */
    'enableSorting'=>true,
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns' => array(
     )
);
```

Then in your model

```
public function search()
{

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('field1',$this->field1,true);

    $criteria->compare('field2',$this->field2);

    return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'field1 ASC',
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>20
        ),
    ));
}
```